# How to sort a UNIQUE()-generated list based upon values from an independent column?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

Can and how do I get the `UNIQUE()`-generated list in column `B` to automatically sort (in `A->Z` order) based upon the numbers in column `C`, as shown in the image below?

- I want this "unique sort" to update dynamically upon any changes to column `A` and column `C` entries -- ie, humans enter updates to columns `A` and `C`.
- The sheet example shown in the image below contains no additional cell formulas other than the `B1` formula that's already shown.
- I would like to keep the header row text as shown, or similar, even if it means moving the location of any formula/function (say to row `2`).
- All of the `=SORT(UNIQUE())` answers I see thus far on https://webapps.stackexchange.com address less-complex scenarios.

[image: Google Sheets: how to sort output form UNIQUE() function?]

Comment: **Please do share a demo sheet with expected results**. Also, what happens when those numbers change? Do they change? Are they occurrences of column `A`? And should the results be sorted like: green, red, blue, yellow (1, 2, 3, 3)